# How can I increment a value in a data frame without creating a new column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this:

```
chr    start    stop
chr1    1    500
chr1    1000    1500
chr1    1500    1500
```

I need to find the rows where start and stop are the same and increment stop by 1.  So pseudo code might look like this

```
if start = stop, stop+1
```

I would like to use dplyr if possible.  I have found examples that could do this by adding a new column.  I need to edit the value in-line.

My expected outcome for the example data would be:

```
chr    start    stop
chr1    1    500
chr1    1000    1500
chr1    1500    1501
```

Where the value for row 3 column `stop` increased by 1.

Comment: Both answers are correct and the same.  Makes it hard to decide which one to call the accepted answer!  I gave the acceptance to @Omar since he might benefit considering a lower overall profile count.

Comment: @akrun  You are right, I hadn't considered that possibility.  Accepted solution changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use this simple solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(stop = ifelse(start == stop, stop + 1, stop))

   chr start stop
1 chr1     1  500
2 chr1  1000 1500
3 chr1  1500 1501
```

Answer (score 2):

```
chr <- rep("chr1",3)
start <- c(1,1000, 1500)
stop <-c(500,1500,1500)


df <- data.frame(chr,start,stop)

df %>%
  mutate(stop = ifelse(start == stop, stop+1,stop))
```